# sorting on files and joining

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sort, join

I have two files. I want to sort the file and join on the first column. For example:

First file:

```
100.   ttt
200.   616te
300.   7a27
       7373qq
```

second file:

```
100.   ttt
200.   yoga
300.   7a27
       8371gd
```

In order to join the two files I do the following:

```
join <(sort first_file.txt) <(sort second_file.txt) >joined.txt
```

I want the resulting output to be:

```
100.   ttt.      ttt
200.   616te.    yoga
300.   7a27.     7a27
       7373qq.   8371gd
```

And then I want to see the lines where column 2 and column 3 are different. For that I do:

```
awk '$2!=$3 {print $1, $2, $3}' joined.txt >different.txt
```

As you can see some of the values in the first two files are null. And therefore, when I use join I get the following error for example:

```
join: /dev/fd/63:26456: is not sorted: 100  7373qq
join: /dev/fd/62:23295: is not sorted: 100  8371gd
```

How can I take care of this? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you _need_ the intermediate file `joined.txt` for any other purposes, or would you also be happy with a solution that simply compares the "key-value"-associations of both input files and prints the differences?

Comment: Thank you! Solution that compares key-value association will also be fine.

Comment: ... and what should happen for the case(s) where the key is empty? also, how are the columns of your files delimited?

Comment: Yes they are delimited by a space. And if key is empty then I want to see if the corresponding value is present in both files. If it is then that won't count as a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output including cases where this doesn't do what you want:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t[^ ]* */.\t/'
100.   ttt.     ttt
200.   616te.   yoga
300.   7a27.    7a27
       7373qq.  8371gd
```

If you need the above intermediate output as well as the final comparison output then:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t[^ ]* */.\t/' | tee intermediate | awk '($NF".")!=$(NF-1)'
200.   616te.   yoga
       7373qq.  8371gd
```

or if you don't then just:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{sub(/\t[^ ]* */,".\t")} ($NF".")!=$(NF-1)'
200.   616te.   yoga
       7373qq.  8371gd
```

or if you don't actually need a `.` added at the end of the 2nd field values:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{sub(/\t[^ ]* */,"\t")} $NF!=$(NF-1)'
200.   616te    yoga
       7373qq   8371gd
```